# Update a field in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several tables that have a common field (column) called `LastName` in a `MySQL database`. Several of the rows in these tables are in mixed case so they don't get selected properly when doing a `SELECT`.

How can I convert those columns to all UPPER CASE? I can easily handle any new entries to convert them to upper case, but the existing records I'm not so sure about.

Comment: You've got the answers below, but you can also add WHERE LastName <> UPPER(LastName) to keep transaction size down.

Comment: @jarlh : I was just going to add the same comment - but with the caveat that this may have an impact on query speed with large tables.

Comment: Does MySQL support collations? I'd rather alter the column to a case insensitive collation in that case, which mean names is stored as enterd, but search is done case insensitive.

Comment: @jarlh :  I have just checked that - unless the string is a binary string - then string comparisons should be case-insensitive. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Speed is not an issue because this is going to be a one time conversion.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would work:

```
UPDATE table_name SET `column_name` = UPPER( `column_name` )
```

Answer (score 2):

would do the job

```
update table set LastName=UPPER(LastName);
```

NOTE - if you are running from MySQL workbench you may have to disable safety mode or add a where clause (eg WHERE id>0) otherwise it wont run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string function `UPPER()` to make the column value to upper

```
update Your_table set LastName=UPPER(LastName)
```